# No error message or status, just getting re-routed back to my signin

Tags: express, bcrypt, nodemon, body-parser

The issue is a signin function. The function is suppose to take the input-email and input-password, send it to backend and compare it the saved email and password, then send id they both are equal then send data "success" back and refreash to "home"-screen. However it keep rerouting back to signin-screen. with no error message, only with Firefox I get a error message, except for that Im clueless.

**Front-end:**

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
      console.log('home')
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: this.state.signInEmail,
          password: this.state.signInPassword
        })
      })
      
        .then(response => response.json)
        .then(data => {
          if (data === 'success') {
            this.props.onRouteChange('home');
          } 
        })
    }
```

**Back-end:**

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    if(req.body.email === database.users[0].email &&
        req.body.password === database.users[0].password) {
            res.json('success');
            console.log('success');
        } else {
            console.log('error');
            res.status(400).json('error logging in');
        }
        
})
```

**My Json dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13"
  }
```

Comment: you are only returning the `json` method -- not calling it.

`.then(response => response.json)`
should be
`.then(response => response.json())`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I corrected the error accordingly, however I still get the same result. Is there anything else im not doing correctly. Appreciate all help :) 

 .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          if (data === 'success') {
            this.props.onRouteChange('home');
          } 
        })
    }